# Monitoring my Main XP PC

Tags: c#, windows-mobile, windows-ce

I want to program a small Windows Mobile Application, which Monitors my Main XP PC. IT should check if my PC is running and if the Internet connection is ok (perhaps by pinging a Sever).

In case something is wrong my Mobile Application should send me a SMS through the Mobile  using mobile network (not through the Internet).

Is this possible can you provide me with some ideas?

Comment: Welcome to SO!  You should try to solve the problem first and post specfic questions, not a wishlist for a complete walkthrough.  Break the problem down into bits and solve each individually.  Good luck!

Comment: You might consider asking a question or deleting this post before the negative reputation starts pouring in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should look into WMI - it allows you to query a windows computer and gather all sorts of data; network information, hardware information, resource usage, the list goes on.

I've no experience with Windows Mobile so I'm unsure about whether you can perform WMI queries from it, however if not you could create an ASP.NET based interface which performs the actual WMI calls. You could then visit the ASP.NET page from your mobile device. The other option which operates in a similar fashion is using web services and calling these from your mobile app.

Here is the MSDN section on WMI: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394582.aspx

Edit: Actually I went off on a bit of a tangent there; this idea doesn't use the mobile network as asked, my apologies.